# Saving javascript object into database with php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a `javascript` object (with `stringify`, i can make it in `json` format), like that:

```
var jsObject ={'elem1':'val1', 'elem2': {'elem21':'val1', 'elem22': 'val2'}};
```

I want to save it in my already prepared database, and that using `php` of course. My problem, is how can i communicate with that js object so that i can save its elements into my db using `php`? for example, i my use `json_encode()`

any help

Comment: send variable to a php page or use ajax

Comment: i can prepare php page for saving info in db, but how can i send my js object to it as you proposed? thanks

Comment: @HoussemBdr Execute a HTTP request with JS (AJAX), posting the JSON string along with it. On your target (PHP) page you will have the JSON string in the `$_POST[]` or `$_GET[]` super global.

Comment: @AlexP I am working on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the serialize function ported from php in php.js:
http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize/
or you can te parseJSON function by jquery
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
or the javascript native object
JSON.stringify(obj);

Using jquery:

```
$.post('file.php', {
    data_to_save: JSON.stringify(obj)
}, function (r) {
    alert(r)
});
```

in php

```
$data_from_js = $_POST['data_to_save']; //It's a string contains the "jsonizzed" javascript object
//Do the query to save string from $data_from_js to database
echo "success";
```

Comment: Sorry but you did not understand what i asked for